# GitLab CI/CD unset variables set in CI / CD Settings

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running a gitlab job and in the job I'm trying to unset certain variables set in CI / CD Settings.

For example, I have
`SOME_VARIABLE` set to `<some_value>`

Then, in the job definition, I'm trying

```
variables:
   SOME_VARIABLE: ""
script:
    - echo SOME_VARIABLE - [%SOME_VARIABLE%]
```

But in the job itself I'm still getting

`SOME_VARIABLE - [<some_value>]`

instead of

`SOME_VARIABLE - []`

Has anyone came across this?

Comment: Can you show your .gitlabci.yml file? It may be caused by Gitlab CI interpreting your double quote before script as empty and still reusing the old one. Maybe if you put a space instead or another neutral value

Comment: Yup come across this multiple times and it's very annoying.

Answer (score 6):

I'll have to answer this since it might be rather obscure.

So turns out when you set a variable on Windows, you have to say

`set v=some_value`

To unset it, it needs to be

`set v=`

not

`set v=''`

When you set it to empty string it will be that, just quotes:

```
$ set v=""
$ echo %v%
""
```

If you unset it to empty correctly, you get:

```
$ set v=
$ echo %v%
%v%
```

However in gitlab, you can't leave values empty, such as

```
variables:
   v:
```

because the it's invalid syntax.

So what I had to do was unset the variable in the script area:

```
script:
  - set v=
  - run_my_script_that_needs_v_unset
```

Then the script worked as needed.

(I imagine it can be done similarly on the other platforms.)

Comment: On Linux, you can just use `unset VARIABLE`. This answer confused me because it's specific to Windows, but the examples start with `$ ` which is typically shown in the Linux command prompt (the Windows command prompt is something else, like `>`, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Project CI/CD variables take precedence over YAML-defined variables. Here's the order of precedence.

1. Trigger variables or scheduled pipeline variables.
2. Project-level variables or protected variables.
3. Group-level variables or protected variables.
4. YAML-defined job-level variables.
5. YAML-defined global variables.
6. Deployment variables.
7. Predefined environment variables.

from [GitLab CI/CD Variables: Priority of variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#priority-of-variables)

Comment: This is technically correct but does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GitLab API to play around with the CI/CD variable. You can either delete it or update it (depending on what suits you)

[Delete Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#remove-variable)
[Update Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable)

Below is the gitlab job to do the delete of variable named **SOME_VARIABLE**

```
cleanup-Variable:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl
    - 'STATUS_CODE="$(curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${YOUR_PROJECT_TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/variables/CR_NUMBER")"'
- echo "Status code for delete variable is  $STATUS_CODE"
- if [[ $STATUS_CODE == "204" ]]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi
  when: always
```

Edite answer. The Delete API returns 204 instead of 200. And no response body hence we have to use **-s -w "%{http_code}\n"** flags in curl command

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `=` just do `set <varible-name>`

Example:

```
 before_script:
    - set S3_OBJECTS
    - source ./s3-objects.sh
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it probably should've been a comment on [Gyuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55204041/399105)